# Windows Phone Contacts fetch/update from device

Tags: c#, performance, windows-phone-8.1, contacts

I am developing Windows Phone app (Windows Phone 8.1), and I need to have user's contacts updated in my app.

Currently I am fetching all contacts from the device on each application startup or from a background task once in a while:

```
var contactStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync();
var collectionOfContact = await contactStore.FindContactsAsync();
```

This operation costs me a lot, cause I am doing intersections with the new fetched collection and my previous data - I need to check for new and deleted users in order to perform an update on my contacts.

Is there any way to get only new contacts from the device or the deleted ones? Is there any other approach to accomplish this functionality ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *How* are you performing the intersection?

Comment: It can be a bit of confising to exaplain all the details in the comment area. Basicly, I am gettings the users colleciton and I iterate on it, my identification is bsed on phone number - which means that if I had two diffrent users with the same phone I'll peak the first one (alphabeticly)... If I could filter the contacts to only changed(relevant) it could boost my performance